# Next and Previous in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure if anyone has done something similar before.

Here's the scenario: I load mysql result into PHP array which is then added into a session. I want to be able to press two buttons (previous/next) to move through the results. Is this something feasible?

Here's my code:

```
include('config.php');

$con = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password); 

if(!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

mysql_select_db('members', $con) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM people where status like 'married' ";  
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $result_array[] = $row['id'];
}

return $result_array;

session_start();
$_SESSION['theResult'] = $result_array; 

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: You want a paginator with 1 item per page.

Comment: @Mike - That is right, I have a page which displays the result, and when the buttons (previous/next) are pressed should show another result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

untested but would something like this work??

```
$_SESSION["current"] = $_SESSION["current"] || 0;
if(isset($_POST["move"])) {
   if($_POST["move"] == "prev") {
        echo $_SESSION['theResult'][$_SESSION["current"] == 0 ? 0 : $_SESSION["current"]--];
   } else if($_POST["move"] == "next") {
        echo $_SESSION['theResult'][$_SESSION["current"] == count($_SESSION['theResult'])-1 ? count($_SESSION['theResult'])-1 : $_SESSION["current"]++];
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code looks quite to the point, will try it out now and let you know it it works.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need at least two session variables:

1. Array list
2. Index (offset) counter
3. (optional) "Items per page" counter, but this can be hard-coded

Start off with an array of items in the session, and an index of 0. The "next" button increments the offset by N (where N is the number of items to display on the page).
Prev decrements it. (All the while checking to make sure we have enough items to when the switch is made). So, for example, if you had a list of 10 items and we wanted to show three per page:

```
$_SESSION['item'] = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j');
$_SESSION['offset'] = 0;
$itemsPerPage = 3;
```

Any call to next/prev would change `$_SESSION['offset']` by `$itemsPerPage` amount (either positively or negatively). Then, displaying the items is a matter of:

```
$end = $_SESSION['offset'] + $itemsPerPage;
if ($end >= sizeof($_SESSION['items']))
{
  // never go past the number of items we have
  $end = sizeof($_SESSION['items']) - 1;
}
for ($i = $_SESSION['offset']; $i < $end; $i++){
  //output $_SESSION['items'][$i];
}
```

*For a single item display, `$itemsPerPage` becomes moot, all you need to track is `$_SESSION['offset']` and display the item from the session array at that stored offset. e.g.*

```
$currentItem = $_SESSION['offset'];

//output $_SESSION['items'][$currentItem];
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazing example, will see if I can get it to work. I appreciate it a lot :)

Comment: Why session variables and not page numbers from the request string?

Comment: @MikeB: No particular reason, just was keeping it session-based. But it's completely feasible to use a `$_GET` variable instead of the session variable.

Comment: @mike-b - could you show me how you this could be done without using a session?